# Select com angular carregando valor em branco

Tags: angularjs

Bom eu quero que o select inicie com um valor selecionado, esse valor ja vem no meu ng-model:

```
   <label class="format">SELECIONE:</label>
        <span class="format">
            <select   name="grupo" id="grupo"  data-ng-model="vm.grupoSelecionado.codigo">
                <option  data-ng-repeat="grupo in vm.listaGrupos" value="{{ grupo.codigo }}">{{grupo.descricao}}</option>
            </select>
        </span>
```

ou seja, meu vm.grupoSelecionado.codigo   ja vem meu valor selecionado, o mesmo está dentro da lista do ng-repeat, como iniciar ele carregado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize `ng-options` como fonte de seus dados. Quando presente em um elemento `SELECT`, ele permite a seleção por padrão do valor indentificado pelo termo-chave `track by`.

No exemplo a seguir eu utilizei o mesmo objeto presente na sua questão (`vm`) para demonstrar este comportamento:

```js
function SampleController($scope) {
  $scope.vm = {
    listaGrupos: [
      {codigo: 'a', descricao: 'Grupo A'},
      {codigo: 'b', descricao: 'Grupo B'},
    ],
    grupoSelecionado: {grupo: {codigo: 'b'}} 
  };
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">

      <label class="format">SELECIONE:</label>
      <span class="format">
        <select name="grupo" id="grupo"
                data-ng-model="vm.grupoSelecionado.grupo"
                ng-options="g.descricao for g in vm.listaGrupos track by g.codigo"
                >
        </select>
      </span>
      <br/>
      Selecionado: {{ vm.grupoSelecionado }}

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ao executar este código, perceba que o elemento SELECT é inicializado com o grupo B pré-selecionado.

Comment: Eu fiz dessa forma, e continua vindo em branco o selecionado.

Comment: @WarLock o exemplo acima funciona para você?

Comment: Logicamente sim, porem nao funciona.

Comment: meu  vm.grupoSelecionado.  tem um objeto, grupo, então é assim,  vm.grupoSelecionado.grupo   muda algo? eu tinha esquecido de postar aqui

Comment: @WarLock esta informação não estava presente na pergunta original - sim, muda; eu ajustei o exemplo.

Comment: Funcionou, o problema era no backend que estava vindo o código errado. (diferente do que estava no select) então ele nao ia encontrar nunca, mas seu exemplo me salvou. VLW

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que falte alguma coisa no seu javascript (angular) para funcionar.

Exemplo:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope)
{
    $scope.id = {'id': 1};
    $scope.list = [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'comunidade'},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'csharp'}
    ];
});
```

Nesse código javascript (angular) eu defini que o `id` é aonde meu *select* deve selecionar.

No meu HTML ficaria nesse formato:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <select id="select1" name="select1" ng-model="id" ng-options="s.name for s in list track by s.id">
   </select>
<div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope)
{
    $scope.id = {'id': 1};
    $scope.list = [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'comunidade'},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'csharp'}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<select id="select1" name="select1" ng-model="id" ng-options="s.name for s in list track by s.id">
</select>
<div>
```

Comment: Não entendi o ng-options, como ficaria com o meu codigo? o que significa esse S?

Comment: o meu ,vm.grupoSelecionado.codigo ja é exatamente o valor que quero do objeto, pois estou criando uma função editar, então ja vem o que foi selecionado pra editar nela.Quero que meu select inicie com o que vem no vm.grupoSelecionado.descricao

Comment: o ng-options é o cara responsável a dizer ao seu select que o mesmo tem que carregar os itens da `list` o s é para ele saber que o name é o texto e o id é o value do option do seu select

Comment: Sobre o vm.grupoSelecionado ele tem como característica posicionar o item do select pela objeto referente ao {'id':1}!, foi o que li no site do angular! e realmente funcionou